# Golang leer un archivo csv de 144513 registros concurrentemente

Tags: revisión-de-código, csv, go

Estoy usando el siguiente archivo de la base de datos de **geonames:**

> http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/MX.zip

La base de datos geográfica *GeoNames* cubre todos los países y contiene más de once millones de nombres de lugares que están disponibles para descargar de forma gratuita.

El archivo tiene: 144513 registros.

Y estoy haciendo un programa en **go** para leerlo concurrentemente y generar dinámicamente unos comandos curl para hacer unos post al api de Elasticsearch y que se puedan cargar los documentos. Es decir que estoy convirtiendo los registros del archivo de formato csv a formato json para cargarlos con el comando curl en Elasticsearch.

El script que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
    "runtime"
)

const (
    FILE                       = "./MX.txt"
    TOTAL_ROWS                 = 144513
    //TOTAL_ROWS                 = 5
    ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX string = "mx"
    ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE  string = "postal_code"
    FILE_DELIMITER             = '\t'
)

type Document struct {
    cp, colonia, ciudad, delegacion, lat, lon string
}

func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    var c chan Document = make(chan Document)

    go readFile(c)
    go toCurl(c)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)

}

func readFile(c chan Document) {

    file, err := os.Open(FILE)
    printError(err)
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    reader.Comma = FILE_DELIMITER

    rows, err := reader.ReadAll()
    printError(err)

    for n, each := range rows {

        n++
        if n <= TOTAL_ROWS {
            c <- Document{
                    cp: each[1], 
                    colonia: each[2], 
                    ciudad: each[3], 
                    delegacion: each[5], 
                    lat: each[9], 
                    lon: each[10],
                }
        }
    }

}

func toCurl(c chan Document) string {

    for {

        id := uuid.NewV4().String()

        d := <-c

        curl :=
            `
            curl -u elastic:changeme  -X PUT "http://$ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:$ELASTICSEARCH_PORT/` + ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX + `/` + ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE + `/` + id + `" -d "
            {
                \"cp\"         : \"` + d.cp + `\",
                \"colonia\"    : \"` + d.colonia + `\",
                \"ciudad\"    : \"` + d.ciudad + `\",
                \"delegacion\"    : \"` + d.delegacion + `\",
                \"location\": {
                    \"lat\": ` + d.lat + `,
                    \"lon\": ` + d.lon + `
                }
            }"
        `
        //fmt.Println(curl)
        out, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", curl).Output()
        printError(err)
        fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", string(out))
    }

}

func printError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\nError: %v \n ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Y funciona.
Pero mi duda es:

Quiero saber si realmente estoy haciendo buen uso de los conceptos de channels y goroutines para hacer mejor y mas rapido el proceso.
O si hay alguno sugerencia por parte de ustedes para mejorar el programa o los procesos.

Comment: en este código tenés exactamente un productor y un consumidor, en un canal que tiene 0 o 1 objetos. No estás ganando mucho con las goroutines. Puede tener sentido (considerando que la parte más lenta es elastic) que tengas muchos consumidores indexando los documentos. Por otro lado, mirá la [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). Ahora estás abriendo y cerrando una conexión HTTP por cada documento. Eso es overhead que podés evitar haciendo bulk inserts

Answer (score 0):

Podemos decir que lo que has implementado con channels es esto exactamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto como te definen en los comentarios es empleando llamadas tipo Bulk, pero ya que este caso es una implementación que la puedes tener en más de un caso donde no existan operaciones bulk puedes emplear lo que se llama una cola con un buffer y emplear un pull de conexiones por lo que irás mucho más rápido procesando, en el caso que nos comentas arriba es posible emplear un diseño tal que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Teniendo dos elementos que suben a Elastic podrías procesar el 50% más rápido sobre el papel.